# Appending Random Number to Existing List

Tags: manipulate, random

My goal is to append random number to list like below.The problem is whenever I try appending a random number, the previously created numbers are changed which I don't know why. How to add a random number without changing existing number?

```
Manipulate[ Nest[(Append[#, RandomInteger[10]]) &, {}, i], {i, 1, 5, 1}]}]
```

[image]

[image]

※Althogh I tried Nest and Pure function as above,  result was happened as the same as code below.

```
Manipulate[ Table[RandomInteger[10], i], {i, 1, 5, 1}]
```

Comment: Generate first, display later: `SeedRandom[1];
With[{num = Nest[(Append[#, RandomInteger[10]]) &, {}, 5]},
 Manipulate[num[[1 ;; i]], {i, 1, 5, 1}]
 ]` ? or please elaborate how you intend to use this.

Comment: Or start with a fixed seed: `Manipulate[Nest[(Append[#, RandomInteger[10]]) &, SeedRandom[1]; {}, i], {i, 1, 5, 1}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just hide/reveal parts of a randomly generated list, you can do this:

```
With[
  {listLength = 5},
  With[
    {fullList = RandomInteger[10, listLength]},
    Manipulate[Take[fullList, i], {i, 1, 5, 1}]]]
```

If you want "real time" randomness, you might do something like this:

```
DynamicModule[
  {list = {}, maxLength = 5},
  Manipulate[
    list = PadRight[list, len, RandomInteger[10]], 
    {{len, 0}, 0, maxLength, 1}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments;using the random number seed.It was simple matter,which I now realize.

`Manipulate[SeedRandom[1]; Table[RandomInteger[10], i], {i, 1, 5, 1}]`

Comment: But this is just showing more or less of essentially a fixed list. If that's all you wanted, you could have just generated that list beforehand.